# How to construct a case insensitive enum?

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums

I have a simple Python 2.7 enum:

```
from enum import Enum

class Label(enum):
    RedApple = 1
    GreenApple = 2
```

I would like to be able create enum objects using case-insensitive keys:

```
fruitname = "redapple"
a = Label[fruitname]
```

I've tried to create an `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, key):
    super(Label, self).__init__()
    pass # do comparison here
```

but I keep running into errors:

```
super(Label, self).__init__()
NameError: global name 'Label' is not defined
```

I'd like to do a comparison on `key.lower().strip()`. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Python 3.6 and [`aenum 2.0`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)<sup>1</sup><sup>2</sup> (which is compatible with 2.7 and 3.0+) a new method has been added: `_missing_`<sup>2</sup>.

This method is called just before a `ValueError` is raised to give custom code a chance to try and find the enum member *by value*.  Unfortunately, this makes it unsuited for your use-case -- looking up by name.

Fortunately, `aenum` has the extra option of defining a `_missing_name_` method<sup>3</sup> which will be called when name lookup fails.

Your code above should look like this:

```
from aenum import Enum

class Label(Enum):

    RedApple = 1
    GreenApple = 2

    @classmethod
    def _missing_name_(cls, name):
        for member in cls:
            if member.name.lower() == name.lower():
                return member
```

And in use:

```
>>> Label['redapple']
<Label.RedApple: 1>
```

---

If stuck using the 3.6 stdlib (or want to stay compatible with it) you can (ab)use `_missing_` but:

- you will have to do `Label('redapple')` instead (round parens, not square brackets), and
- you will be working against the design of enum ('redapple' is the name, not the value)

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

<sup>2</sup> [`enum34`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) does not have these improvements as it is only being maintained for bug fixes.

<sup>3</sup> `_missing_value_` is preferred in `aenum` as it is more explicit about what it is checking, but it falls back to `_missing_` for compatibility with the stdlib.

<sup>4</sup> aenum v2.0.2 has a bug where `_missing_` is called for both values and names if `_missing_name_` has not been overridden -- this is fixed in v2.0.3+.

Comment: Great answer!  Thanks!

Comment: Okay.  I'm testing this and finding that _missing_ is not getting called.

Comment: `ValueError: redapple is not a valid Label`

Comment: @Hephaestus:  Latest version of [`aenum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) is now available.

Comment: Great.  Thanks.  I'm using aenum 2.0.1.
Your fix with the parenthesis is right on.  
This works perfectly.

Comment: @Hephaestus:  Upgrade to 2.0.2 and both methods will work properly.  :)

Comment: Interesting to note the `pip` is only allow for `aenum` 2.0.1 at this time.  I'll go to the source.  Thanks.

Comment: @Hephaestus:  Just realized I had recommended a bad approach -- reworked answer.

Comment: Using `casefold` instead of `lower` is recommended for doing case-insensitive string comparisons

Comment: It looks like this is part of python 3.11 now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68311691/10559526

Comment: @Malaber: it is not.  That answer is using another dunder method to implement a similar solution.

Answer (score 9):

Not 100% sure this will work in Python 2.7, but I came up with a simple way to make it work exactly as requested for Python 3.6+.

The idea is that lookup for names is done by the class using square brackets, which means that it uses `__getitem__` from the metaclass. So you can make a simple metaclass that implements a case insensitive search. Since it will extend the existing `EnumMeta`, it will be totally compatible with existing enums:

```
class CaseInsensitiveEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, str):
            item = item.upper()
        return super().__getitem__(item)
```

This presupposes that your enums are all uppercase. Using it is pretty straightforward:

```
class Label(Enum, metaclass=CaseInsensitiveEnumMeta):
    REDAPPLE = 1
    GREENAPPLE = 2
```

I'm not sure you even need `Enum` in this case. The catch here is that your enums have to be all uppercase for this to work. If you want to have a truly insensitive search, you would have to make sure that all of the keys in `__members__` are properly casefolded.

In the meantime, you can do

```
>>> Label['GreenApple']
Label.GREENAPPLE
```

Answer (score 8):

enum have *missing* function which can be overridden to make enum case insensitive.
As per documentation
https://docs.python.org/3.11/howto/enum.html
*missing* – a lookup function used when a value is not found; may be overridden

**example**

```
class Status(enum.Enum):
    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        for member in cls:
            if member.value == value.upper():
                return member
    SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS'
    FAILURE = 'FAILURE'

print(Status('success'))
```

**Output**

```
Status.SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't wanted to define this validation in the enum class, this is a general functionality I want to reuse. So I decided to do this in an MetaEnum:

```
from enum import Enum, auto, EnumMeta

class CaseInsensitveKeys(EnumMeta):
    def __getitem__(cls, item):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(item)
        except:
            for key in cls._member_map_.keys():
                if key.casefold() == item.casefold():
                    return super().__getitem__(key)

class DatabaseType(Enum, metaclass=CaseInsensitveKeys):
    PostgreSQL = auto()
    Oracle = auto()
```