# Python case insensitive Enums

Tags: python, string, enums

I'm trying to build case insensitive enums and I found an answer which helps in certain cases:

```
from enum import StrEnum, auto

class Fruits(StrEnum):

    DRAGON_FRUIT = auto()
    APPLE = auto()

    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        value = value.lower()
        for member in cls:
            if member == value:
                return member
        return None

if Fruits.DRAGON_FRUIT == "dragon_fruit":
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)

if Fruits.DRAGON_FRUIT == "dragon_Fruit":
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)

if Fruits.APPLE == "apple":
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)

if Fruits.APPLE == "Apple":
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

the result is: `True`, `False`, `True`, `False`.

I'm not able to add print statements to the `_missing_` method, but it seems to me that this should work because it runs lower on the value and then, just does a comparison.

Comment: `value.lower()` should be `value.upper()` since the actual names are uppercase. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68311691/1491895

Comment: `if member == value` should be `if member.name == value`

Comment: To compare directly, you can override `__eq__` method.

Comment: @Barmar: the strings are not being compared to the name, but to the member itself, so `_missing_` is never called (and the linked answer is not referring to equality checks).  Your second comment is also incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_missing_` method is to help when accessing an enum:

```
Fruit('dragon_fruit')
Fruit('DraGon_frUit')
Fruit('DRAGON_FRUIT')
```

The first attempt above succeeds naturally because `Fruit.DRAGON_FRUIT.value == 'dragon_fruit'`  The second and third succeed because your `_missing_` method is called and does a lowered search on the members looking for `'dragon_fruit'`.

All of that means that `_missing_` and `==` are not related *at all*.  Your `if`/`else` blocks are equivalent to

```
if "dragon_fruit" == "dragon_fruit":
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)

if "dragon_fruit" == "dragon_Fruit":
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

etc.

To find out if a certain string, ignoring case, is in your enum you need something like:

```
some_value = 'DRAGON_fruit'
try:
    fruit = Fruit(some_value)
except ValueError:
    # do something when string is not a valid value
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.